# check if user installed whats-app or whats-app business

Tags: android, package, whatsapp

I'd like to check a condition before starting an activity in my app. I'd like to check if the user has installed the conventional WhatsApp or WhatsApp business. I check the name of the package of both the apps. However, I get an exception despite that I already have WhatsApp on my phone.

This is the code I use to check the package name

```
 private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and I use this method in my onCreate method

```
 private void checkwhatsversion() {

        PackageManager pm = mainactivity.this.getPackageManager();
        boolean isInstalled1 = isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp", pm);
        boolean isInstalled2 = isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp.w4b", pm);

        if(isInstalled1) {
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (isInstalled2) {
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add these two lines to your `Manifest`  File. and then after use your code is working

```
 <queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```
 private fun pickWhatsappPackageName(activity: Activity): String? {

        val w4bPackageName = "com.whatsapp.w4b"
        val wpPackageName = "com.whatsapp"

        var packageName: String? = w4bPackageName

        val pm = activity.packageManager
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(w4bPackageName,
                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        } catch (exWhatsappForBusiness: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(wpPackageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
                packageName = "com.whatsapp"
            } catch (exWhatsapp: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                packageName = null
            }
        }

        return packageName
    }
```

If the user has Whatsapp business installed, it is going to return the business package, otherwise it returns the usual whatsapp package or null if none exists.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you have not already try with following -

```
 private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, packageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
 }
```

Happy Coding !